# Asterisk Sipml5

Tags: asterisk, sipml

I'm using Duobango SIPML5. But when call is processed this errors appears:
[Apr 17 11:01:05] WARNING[24230][C-00000014]: chan_sip.c:10842 process_sdp: Matched device setup to use SRTP, but request was not! NOTICE[24674][C-00000013]: chan_sip.c:10386 process_sdp: Received SAVPF profle in audio offer but AVPF is not enabled, enabling: audio 58823 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126 [Apr 17 10:56:26] WARNING[24674][C-00000013]: chan_sip.c:10785 process_sdp: Rejecting secure audio stream without encryption details: audio 58823 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126 Can you help me, please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should set *encryption=yes* for the peer in *sip.conf*.

Comment: A helpful link would be to the [Encryption section](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/OutsideConnectivity_id291235.html#OutsideConnectivity_id36002938) of the Asterisk Book. Also, others have found the [Secure Calling Tutorial](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial) helpful.